# Alexa developer console does not recognize endpoint

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I just tried to make my first Alexa skill with Lambda. When I want to set the endpoint, they say that the trigger setting for the Lambda is invalid (see picture). It works in the Lambda tests. How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't add (or didn't **save** the addition of) the "Alexa Skills Kit" trigger in the Lambda function configuration.

Oddly, Amazon doesn't automatically save the trigger when you click the "Add" button:

[image]

You have to **also** click the "Save" button afterward:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @jdunk. I would have been still lost if wasn't for your comment.